# Angular ngx-charts how to get x axis number

Tags: angular, bar-chart, axis, onselect, ngx-charts

I have an Angular Ngx vertical chart , and I need to get only x axis number. I want to use this x axis number at onSelect function.

Html :

```
  <ngx-charts-bar-vertical
        [xAxisLabel]="xAxisLabel"
        [yAxisLabel]="yAxisLabel"
        (select)="onSelect($event)"
        [results]="dataSource">
  </ngx-charts-bar-vertical>
```

DataSource :

> [ {userId: 5, name: "User Name example", value: 69.6} ... ]

I want to get "**userId**" part in fact, but i couldn't . 
When I select a bar , **onSelect** is getting only the "**name**" and the "**value**" parts, but not '**userId**' part.

In reality, i want that the exactly opposite of this stuff 
 : https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-charts/issues/409
Here want to hide allData but i want to get all data when i click a bar.

So i think that :

- Get x axis number
- userId = dataSource[xAxisNumber].userId;

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple solution :
Added an `extra` field only , and it's Ok.

Now my dataSource is like that :

> { name: 'User Name', value: 40,32, extra: { userId: 17  }

so now i can get **extra** field, then I can get use **userId** field .

It helped me :
https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-charts/issues/506

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the name you can use array.find() method to get the userId values as follows,

```
const userId = dataSource.find(t=>t.name === 'onselectedname').userId;
```

Comment: Sorry but this technique doesn't work because of same user names

Comment: then use array.filter() and access the 0th name

Comment: @mevaka what ? i dont get it

Comment: Think about it : 
You have 5 data with same name and value , if you use this technique , you only can show 0ht data every time , but you want to show 0th, 1st , 2nd etc data too..
Yes I know I can create a helper variable for counting how many times I clicked and reference it , but same value set is not only one ,  for example I have 100 data , 5 of them's value is 6, 7 of them's value is 5 etc..
I want to access only the number of data that  referencing exactly what I clicked, because I have a lot of data and some of them are really same.